# Use textract to get txt from a docx but the numbers are ignored in python

Tags: python, docx, text-extraction, python-docx

I'm trying to get section number before each paragraph. But the weird thing is when I using textract to get txt from some docx. The numbers are ignored. Is there a way to get these numbers back?
EX:
1.Term. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXend

I only got 'Term. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXend' in txt. I guess when these section are inputed within word's numbering feature, they will be ignored

```
text = textract.process(url, extension='docx')
strText = text.decode("utf8")
children = strText.split('\n\n')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without solving your core problem, I can always recommend using builtin open() and readline() as an alternative.

Comment: Yeah, that would be better. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're hypothesis is correct. The section numbers are not actually stored in the document, they are computed and displayed at runtime only.

The only way to get them is to keep track yourself based on what may be the style of those paragraphs, something like 'Heading 1' and 'Heading 2' etc. It's possible for them to be assigned other ways which make it more difficult, but often it's done with headings since that's so easy for the author.

Comment: Appreciated, I'm trying to handling some contracts, that would be time consuming if operate manually. I will keep searching for a way out.

Comment: When I said "keep track of them yourself" I meant in your code, not by hand :) So you would iterate the paragraphs in the document, check their style, and increment a counter for each one that's "Heading 1", another counter for those that are "Heading 2", probably reseting the Heading 2 counter when you hit a new Heading 1, etc.